# Using internal HA proxy in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, haproxy, virtual-ip-address

We have configured multiple internal (with private IP adresses) haproxy servers namely ha1 and ha2 in different availability zones of same region in aws.

I would like to use keepalived to configure a virtual private IP in these HA servers and point the DNS to the virtual IP.

However, I dont understand how can we configure a virtual IP between two availability zones? How can I achieve this in AWS.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a Network Load Balancer.

You get one static IP per AZ, and you can put your haproxy cluser behind the NLB.